# "wkhtmltopdf" and "pdfkit" gems -- error "ContentNotFoundError". How to fix it?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, heroku

I have a Rails app at heroku. I'm using these 2 gems for generating pdf files:

```
gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", "~> 2.12", ">= 2.12.3.0"
gem "pdfkit", "~> 0.8.2"
```

I sometimes, but not always, I have an error:

```
 ContentNotFoundError
```

It's probably due to a bug in the C++ library on top on which the gem is built - https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2051

There's even a workaround as they say.

My question -- if that workaround really works, how can it be applied to the gem? How to get rid of the exception in the gem?